# ng no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm, angular-cli

Quiero crear un proyecto en angular y me dice "ng" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Ejecuto el comando de `npm install -g @angular/cli` y por alguna razón me lo crea en

> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng

Y no en :

> C:\Users\eduardo.yraola\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Que es donde están todas las cosas de `npm.` agregue al `path` ambas rutas por si las dudas, pero cuando quiero hacer el `ng new proyecto` me dice

> "ng" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Alguna recomendación?

Comment: ¿Has cerrado el cmd y luego abrirlo despúes de cambiar los `path`?

Answer (score 5):

Aqui tienes algo similar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Todo apunta que nolo tienes en el Path
intenta con

```
npm run ng <command>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, si consideras que el contenido del enlace ayuda a resolver la duda entonces eres mas que bienvenido a traducirlo y colocarlo aquí, dejando al final los créditos a su autor. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, Revisa por favor  [answer] y wdita tu respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Como es windows quizás tienes que utilizar el símbolo del sistema de NodeJS en lugar del comando de Windows, el símbolo del sistema de NodeJs reconocerá ng.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

@Denis Alayza también sale lo mismo desde el command prompt de NodeJS,al menos cuando recién instalo angular 6, typescript e intento ejecutar ng new .. incluso con npm run new app[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso Windows10, tuve que ayar el path manualmente y tipear en consola:

```
cd C:\Users\MiUsuarioPC\node_modules\.bin
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/212441)

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras entonces que quede como comentario, mi respuesta, para mí resolvió el problema y está totalmente relacionada al tema